# why sometimes I get overflow and sometimes not in C

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I have this code, and the two calculations give me different results.
The first does an overflow and the second just stays with 2^31-1.

I can't figure out why.

```
int n4, n5;

n4 = pow(2, 31);
n4 = n4 + n4;
n5 = pow(2, 31) + pow(2, 31);

printf("\nn4: %d, n5: %d",n4,n5);
/* n4: -2, n5: 2147483647 */
```

Comment: Signed integer arithmetic overflow leads to *undefined behavior*. On most systems `int` is 32 bits wide (and it's always signed). On a two's complement system it can go up to `(2^31)-1` at most.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please make it a habit to use *trailing* newline in your `printf` calls. If connected to a terminal or console window, output to `stdout` (where `printf` rites) is *line* buffered, which means output is actually written one newline. By printing leading newlines you write the *previous* line not the current. And there won't be a newline between the last output and the command-line prompt.

Comment: Seeing the answer by Allan Wind below, I recommend to focus on what exactly is puzzling you. At a guess you are convinced to do the same thing (adding 2 to the power of 31 to itself) and get different results. Or maybe that when adding it to itself you find it strange that the result is it minus 1. Focus on what you are actually wondering about, reduce the guessing needed to answer helpfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value of `pow` is of type `double`.

So, `pow(2, 31) + pow(2, 31)` is in the range a `double` can represent.

The assignment `n5 = (double) ...` casts the `double` to an `int`. But since the value is not representable by an `int`, you get (2^31)-1 as result. Basically you clamp the `double` value to the max value of an `int` ((2^31)-1).

The first case is an overflow, because the result of `n4 + n4` is of type `int`. And the value exceeds the maximum.

### C Standard Draft N2176

**6.3 Conversions

6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**

> 1. When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool,  the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

Yes, the conversion is UB. But to explain the result of the OP, i 'assumed' that the value has been clamped to the range of an `int`.

Comment: You already got my upvote. To harvest more, I recommend that you cite sources for "Basically you clamp the double value to the max value of an int ((2^31)-1)."

Comment: I think that "you clamp" should be more like "gcc clamps". See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/aGK5hrqff

Comment: @Bob__ Interestingly, if you explicitly cast to an `int` like: `n5 = (int) (pow...)`, you get no warning.

Comment: gcc has a bunch of overflow flags if you don't know.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Yeah, an explicit cast tells the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing", even when that's not the case... ;)

Comment: @Bob__ Nice answer.

Comment: The clamping part is nonsense. Nothing tells that should happen.

Comment: @Yunnosch see my answer :D

Comment: @Antti Haapala Please, have a look at my last sentence. I've corrected my answer after the comment of Yunnosch.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, "why sometimes I get overflow and sometimes not" is altogether incorrect. An integer overflow is an erroneous condition that is caused by the result of integer arithmetic not being able to be representable in the type of the expression. What you seem to confuse with it is the `-2`, which is an example of **wraparound, one of the possible manifestations of undefined behaviour of integer overflow**. The problem is that you cannot tell from the result if an integer overflow has happened or not, because the behaviour of the program after integer overflow has happened is undefined so the result can look like it didn't happen.

---

But let's look closer to your code:

```
int n4, n5;

n4 = pow(2, 31);
```

`pow(2, 31)` will result in a double with value of `2` raised to power `31` - exactly or approximately, depending on the quality of the implementation. The exact value is **one** more than the maximum value that can be stored in a 32-bit `signed int`.

A `double` is converted to an `int` by truncating the decimals [(C11/18 6.3.1.4p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p1)

> 1. When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined

And if the integral part is not representable in the target type, the behaviour is undefined. In this case if the `pow` implementation is bad, then the value might be slightly less than 2³¹, and the result, after truncation would equal `MAX_INT` (i.e. 2³¹-1) and no undefined behaviour happens. But if it is good then it results in value 2³¹ and the behaviour of the conversion is undefined.

Now we get to the:

```
n4 = n4 + n4;
```

If `pow(2, 31);` converted to an `int` caused undefined behaviour this already is nonsense. If it didn't (i.e. it resulted in 2³¹-1, then this would cause integer overflow, and thus undefined behaviour would happen here.

```
n5 = pow(2, 31) + pow(2, 31);
```

The value of `pow(2, 31) + pow(2, 31)` will be 2³² of type `double` and not representable in 32-bit `signed int`, hence the conversion will result in undefined behaviour.

And here, undefined behaviour is undefined:

```
printf("\nn4: %d, n5: %d", n4, n5);
/* n4: -2, n5: 2147483647 */
```

Now you think **how exactly** undefined that result is? Well, it is **very** undefined:

If you compile with

```
gcc pow.c
```

and run, you get

```
n4: -2, n5: 2147483647
```

if you compile with `gcc -fno-builtin-pow pow.c -lm`, or ask the exponent `31` with `scanf` say, you'll get

```
n4: 0, n5: -2147483648
```

Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

n4: The first assignment overflows as MAX_INT is probably 2^31-1.  Integer overflow is undefined behavior per 6.3.1.3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

In the next line you add the two undefined values you got before (i.e. -1) and get -2.

n5: `pow()` returns a double so your expression on the right side is done with doubles, then converted to an int which is also undefined behavior per per 6.3.1.4:

> If the value being converted is in the
> range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the
> nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.

Comment: You're quoting the wrong paragraph in the latter quote

Comment: Actually both of them are are wrong. See the other answer.

Comment: Actually the other answer is wrong too in the first paragraph :D what a mess.